# Несколько header на OpenCart

Tags: php, html, opencart

Нужно на главной странице сделать другой header, сайт на OpenCart, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=opencart+custom+header&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

если у вас дефолтная тема, то шаблон хедера лежит по пути:

```
\catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\header.tpl
```

его контроллер соответственно по пути:

```
\catalog\controller\common\header.php
```

редактируйте как душе угодно